# Admob Native AD error causes RecyclerView to disappear with all items

Tags: java, android, kotlin, admob, google-play-services

When I scroll the RecyclerView after showing an ad, all RecyclerView items disappear.
I have a RecyclerView which shows items with GridLayoutManager 3 items vertically but every 40 items shows Admob Native AD as one item vertically using RecyclerView adapter

```
val layoutManager: GridLayoutManager = if (resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    GridLayoutManager(this, 3)
                } else {
                    GridLayoutManager(this, 5)
                }
            // Create a custom SpanSizeLookup where the first item spans both columns
            layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : SpanSizeLookup() {
                override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                    return if (position != 0 && (position + 1) % 40 == 0) {
                        3
                    } else {
                        1
                    }
                }
            }
            recyclerView!!.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

adapter code:

```
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val layoutView: View
        return when (i) {
            AdView -> {
                layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(
                    R.layout.ads_in_recy, viewGroup, false
                )
                return ItemViewHolder(layoutView)
            }
            TYPE -> {
                layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(
                    R.layout.cardveiw_item_book, viewGroup, false
                )
                return ItemViewHolder(layoutView)
            }
            else -> {                layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(
                R.layout.cardveiw_item_book, viewGroup, false
            )
                return ItemViewHolder(layoutView)}
        }

    }
---------------
when (viewType) {
            AdView -> {
                MobileAds.initialize(context) { initializationStatus: InitializationStatus? -> }

                    val adLoader2 =
                        AdLoader.Builder(context, context.resources.getString(R.string.nativeAD))
                            .forNativeAd { nativeAd: NativeAd? ->
                                val styles =
                                    NativeTemplateStyle.Builder()
                                        .withMainBackgroundColor(background)
                                        .build()
                                itemViewHolder.template2W!!.setStyles(styles)
                                itemViewHolder.template2W.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
                                itemViewHolder.template2W.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            }.withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                                    if (itemViewHolder.template2W!!.visibility == View.GONE) {
                                        Yandex.yandexNativeAds(context, itemViewHolder.yadAds!!)
                                        if (Yandex.yandexNativeAds(
                                                context,
                                                itemViewHolder.yadAds
                                            )
                                        ) {
                                            val aadRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
                                            itemViewHolder.maAdViewW!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                            itemViewHolder.maAdViewW.loadAd(aadRequest)
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            })
                            .withNativeAdOptions(NativeAdOptions.Builder().build())
                            .build()
                    adLoader2.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
            }
```

the only yellow errors I see in Logcat:

```
2023-07-12 Ads    W  Precache exception                                                     com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfz: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x76fbf20c3758: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                                                                    error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/crypto/fipsmodule/cipher/e_aes.c:1078 0x76fadea2461e:0x00000000)
                                                                                                    error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:294 0x76fadea2461e:0x00000000)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzft.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:5)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzgh.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzk.zzq(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzk.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzuc.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:4)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzui.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaaz.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaeu.zzq(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaeu.zzp(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:68)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaeu.zzg(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:72)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaen.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:17)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaeu.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzrv.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zztq.zzh(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:33)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxb.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:6)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x76fbf20c3758: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                                                                    error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/crypto/fipsmodule/cipher/e_aes.c:1078 0x76fadea2461e:0x00000000)
                                                                                                    error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:294 0x76fadea2461e:0x00000000)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.read(:com.google.android.gms@225014047@22.50.14 (190800-499278674):3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(:com.google.android.gms@225014047@22.50.14 (190800-499278674):6)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:138)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:213)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:51)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:395)
                                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:372)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzft.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@22.0.0:2)
                                                                                                        ... 17 more
2023-07-12  TrafficStats   D  tagSocket(596) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
```

Please help solve the problem

I tried changing AdMob dependency versions

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0'
```